# Branding copy paste from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste

I saw this http://www.tynt.com/... and I loved their services. only I'm trying to develop something custom for me.. They library is large. I'm trying to do this for the past 10 hours.

Here where I got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ctrlDown = false;
    var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86, cKey = 67;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) {
            if (getSelText() != null)
            { alert(getSelText()); }

            ctrlDown = true;
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) {
            ctrlDown = false;
            //alert("Control is NOOOOOOOOOOOOOT  pressed");
        }
    });

    $(".no-copy-paste").keydown(function(e) {
        if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey || e.keyCode == cKey)) return false;
    });
});

function getSelText() {
    var txt = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection();
        if (txt.type == "Range") {
            return txt + " <br /><br /><a href='" + window.location.pathname + "'>View Original Link</a>";
        }
    }
    else if (document.getSelection) {
        txt = document.getSelection();
        if (txt.type == "Range") {
            return txt + " <br /><br /><a href='" + window.location.pathname + "'>View Original Link</a>";
        }
    }
    else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
        if (txt.type == "Range") {
            return txt + " <br /><br /><a href='" + window.location.pathname + "'>View Original Link</a>";
        }
    }
    else return;

    return null;
}
```

The two issues I have:

1. the appended text only worked if I had this line `alert(getSelText());` ... don't know really why.
2. the appended text is not formatted in HTML

I have looked into zeroclipboard, but it uses flash which is arrrah...

Thanks.

Comment: Oh god please don't do this. Hi-jacking the standard function people expect with copy/paste is just terrible.

Comment: @Grillz, also *infuriating*, and typically ensures I'll never again visit that site, or try to promote/share its content.

Comment: @David Thomas Agreed 100%. I'm sure the OP has good intentions and it seems like a cool trick, but things like this serve as annoyances for the savvy, and confusion for the novice.

Comment: lol ... common we just wanna add a cool tag line that says .. Read th full post at URL

Comment: Seems a legit question to me. I have a table with some formatted data, but I'd like to get raw numbers (more decimal precision, no units) when I copy paste into excel.

Comment: Its not trivial to do on your own. If you edit the clipboard and replace it with your own html, it loses any css that isn't inlined, so you have to inline everything yourself. if part of the style comes from a parent element that isn't selected, for example you select some contents of a div, you'll lose the background color unless you can somehow also grab the parent and reapply it, and what if the 2 anchors of the selection have different parents?

Comment: @djjeck for that use case of hijacking the clipboard as plaintext instead of html its a lot simpler